# Desplegar laravel en hosting compartido

Tags: php, laravel, apache, hosting

He estado leyendo sobre como desplegar una aplicación de laravel 5.6 en un servidor compartido, la solución sencilla es mover el contenido de la carpeta 'public' del proyecto a la raíz del hosting para que al ser accedida mediante www.mihosting.com se pueda ver.

Sin embargo en esos mismos debates hay quienes sugerían no mover el contenido de la carpeta public, porque era una mala practica ya que para eso estaban los HTACCESS pero no explicaban como hacerlo.

Si alguien ha podido desplegarlo de forma correcta agradecería explicaran el procedimiento (ya que la raíz del proyecto laravel carece de un index.php y un .htaccess) y algunos empiezan a explicar como si esos archivos ya existieran y sin hacer mención a la carpeta public.

Comment: puedes decirnos como accedes al server? cpanel y ftp?